# How to take the minimum numbers from an array PHP

Tags: php, algorithm

I have a problem with retrieving numbers from an array,
For e.g, I will have an array like this

```
[20, 25, 40, 50, 30, 45, 33, 25]
```

I would like to retrieve the first 3 minimum numbers from the array.
Neither too big nor too small and not to be duplicated
For e.g ouput will be

```
[20, 25, 30]
```

Comment: Apply `array_unique`, sort the result in ascending order, and then pick the first three elements (if that many exist) from the sorted array.

Comment: Yes, 30, sorry.

Answer (score 2):

You can use like this way

```
 $input = [20, 25, 40, 50, 30, 45, 33, 25 , 20];
    $uniq = array_unique($input);
    sort($uniq);
    return  array_slice($uniq, 0, 3);
```